# How to implement the Glasses-Broken particle effective With Spritekit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to implement the Glassed-Broken particle effective with spritekit, for example

http://www.ps123.net/design/UploadFiles_design/200902/20090225090558921.jpg

How to?